# What do you call this part of old windows?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image: Image of an old-school window]

What is the hinged wood covering on old windows called? Is there a proper name for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are **shutters**:

> Each of a pair of hinged panels, often louvered, fixed inside or outside a window that can be closed for security or privacy or to keep out light. — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/shutter)

Many modern homes have external shutters but I’ve never seen them closed (if they can be — I suspect many are just decorative).

See also [9 Types of Shutters to Know (Interior & Exterior)](https://www.bobvila.com/slideshow/shutter-style-9-designs-everyone-should-know-46308)

Comment: Some (modern ones) are very obviously too narrow to cover the window!

Comment: @KateBunting Not only that, most of the fake ones have no hinges and are screwed to the wall with obvious mirror plates.